# iOS NSNotification - Send notification to disabled View

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I have 2 UI views both with controllers attached to a tab controller.

ViewA - Used for authentication (contains login textfields and submit button)

ViewB - Used to display profile.

I have set ViewB to be disabled using the utility manager in storyboard, this is to prevent users clicking on the tab before logging in. Once authenticated in ViewA i want to notify ViewB to enable itself and display the profile.

From googling it appears that using NSNotificationcenter is the best way to do this, I have created a simple postNotifiaction that works fine - but I am unsure where to add the receiver in ViewB, I can not add it in ViewDidLoad because it does not load, and is disabled to start with?

Is notification center the best way to do this?

Also, how do i sent a notification to a view that is disabled?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Apple documentation link above pretty clearly states that NSNotificationCenter does not retain it's observers, thats why you can't release the dataAnalyzer there - it would be dealloc'd and the notification would attempt to post to a nil reference.

Subscribe to the notification(s) in the -init method of each view controller. That ensures the controller has been created and initialized, and makes each controller responsible for it's own actions.

I'm not entirely sure what your question is, could you rephrase it if the above didn't resolve your problem.

Also, be aware NSNotificationCenter will post to all observers, but it is not async - it waits for each one to finish processing the notification before sending to the next object.

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear, I have two views with controllers, ViewB is disabled to prevent a user clicking on it before authenticating in ViewA, after successful authentication I want to send a notification to ViewB to enable itself; allowing the user to click on the tab and access it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you disable the view or the tab button?

If you disable the tab button, you could enable it and switch to the profile tab by doing

```
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = profileViewController;
```

You can place this code in ViewA's view controller. To get the profileViewController, you can use this code instead

```
 self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]
```

Assuming that your profile is at index 1

Comment: Yes the tab I disabled , where do I put this code though? If this in ViewA in the authentication function, how do I set it to profileView?

Comment: You would need to place this code in the class that controls the tab bar instance. Template projects tend to have the AppDelegate of the project be this class.

Comment: This moves to the locked view but the button on the tab bar is still greyed out and disbaled. I have tried doing: self.tabBarController.tabBarItem.enabled = YES; but does not work

Comment: Try doing profileViewController.tabBarItem.enabled = YES instead.

Answer (score 0):

Surely, you have a controller (AppDelegate if anything) that controls the disabled state of ViewB? You could listen for the notification from this controller instance and enable ViewB from it once it receives the notification.

If you must subscribe to the notification from ViewB, then register for it in its (ViewB's) init method (don't forget to unsubscribe from the notification in the dealloc method). This should work because even though the button used to get to ViewB is disabled, the ViewB instance would be instantiated with the launch of your app (or so I assume...).

If you don't instantiate ViewB until the button is tapped, then you must have the controller that enables/disables the ViewB button be in charge of listening for the notification and enabling the button to access ViewB.

Comment: Ok sounds good, I have created th views using storyboard, so I am unsure when it calls init, I will try this now. Edit: It seems init is not called, maybe I should look into setting this in AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

I think this logic is a little ambiguous. This is what I've understood about your application:

-> Tab Bar Controller

---> Controller 1 - Login

---> Controller 2 - Profile (disable as default)

You have not to insert you notify into Controller 2 but in TabBar because it "controls" the other controllers (sorry for the word joke). I think the best solution can bes this:

**TabBar**

Observer of a notification about "user changed" and check it: if user is logged then enable profile controller, if user is anonymous then disable it.

**Controller 1 - Login**

When the user is logged in / logged out fire a notification of "user changed".

That's all, your controller 2 can live without know user state. Let me know if you have problem coding this logic.

Answer (score 0):

Why you not just call `[viewB enableItselfSomehow];` in `-someAuthenticationSucceedFeedback` method?

Registering notifications for just enabling/disabling view is a bad tone as for me